# Naming this oxo-carboxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

On a textbook question, the answer key revealed this structure to be 3-methyl-2-oxopentanoic acid:

[image]

I found this strange, as the carbon from the left (#3) is methyl, but the oxo prefix is on the right for the $\ce{C=O}$. Why is this?

Comment: Why does it not say 3-methyl-5-oxopentanoic acid or 4-methyl-2-oxopentanoic acid? Is the nomenclature correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Why does it not say 3-methyl-5-oxopentanoic acid or 4-methyl-2-oxopentanoic acid? Please explain

Comment: Why would it be either of those? The methyl and oxo groups are right next to each other.

Comment: @ringo how is it correct?

Comment: @ringo methyl (ch3) isn't right next to oxo (C=O)

Comment: It is obviously incorrect. CH3 from either sides is situated at #3.  And how is oxo at 5?

Answer (score 10):

Starting from the group with the highest priority, the carboxylic acid group, we label the longest carbon chain:

[image]

This molecule might otherwise be named a ketone, but since the carboxylic acid group has a higher priority, it is treated as another substituent (oxo), located at the 2 position. The methyl group is attached to the 3 position, hence the name 3-methyl-2-oxopentanoic acid.